# Looking for a authoritative reference on DER (X.509 etc) encoding standards

Tags: reference-request, standards

I'm writing a paper on parsing DER. DER the canonical sister of BER, when it comes to encoding ASN.1, with emphasis on shortest possible encoding. One of the properties that I seek to assure myself of, is that the TLV lengths are always encoded deterministically. This should be in ITU X.690. However, there seems to have been an oversight, and it's not in there. What I have, is a quote that's just out there on the Internet. Some sites have it. It goes:

"Additionally, the shortest possible length encoding must be used"

Obviously, just a random quote from a random website isn't good enough as a reference for a research paper. So what I'm looking for, is where this quote comes from. An authoritative source. This is my question.

Comment: [X.609](https://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-X.690-202102-I/en) §10.1 “The definite form of length encoding shall be used, encoded in the minimum number of octets.” Isn't that what you want? And there are other rules in §8, §10 and §11 about other aspects of the encoding that are supposed to make it canonical and minimal-length.

Comment: Thanks! That is it.